# .htaccess RewriteRule when empty string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to do something like this http://myweb.com//page

If first parameter is not present it process only the second parameter. 
the first is language and its stored in the session but , it can be changed throe  `?lang=en`..

I was trying something like this but it's not working

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_]+)?/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making them 2 separate rules, because the leading slash is removed.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: One more question , how can I put so lang can be even single call like http://localhost/en
and that it work in other two combinations 
http://localhost/page
http://localhost/en/page

Comment: How is `localhost/en` any different than `localhost/page`? What makes one a language and one a page?

Comment: language is just for loading the different language file I haw a en.php fr.php , the page is just for loading different pages , Haw can I make in this example you posted lang work standalone. Thanks

Comment: I don't mean how they are different in your application, but just by looking at `localhost/blah`, how do I know if "blah" is a language or a page? There has to be something to be able to tell them apart, otherwise you'll have to try something else.

Comment: I can only tell that the lang is always two letters and page is much bigger word. And the lang is predefined I haw only eight of them.   Is that helping?

Comment: You'll have to list out where you want each of the URLs to go, perhaps open a new question, reading code in comments is annoying because you can't format. Where does `/en` go? Where does `/page` go? Does the URL change in the address bar?

Comment: Oh, I figure out for ewerry single language i aded `RewriteRule ^en$ index.php?lang=en [L,QSA]` can I do it like that ?

Answer (score 1):

On a previous language-switchable site i did, i opted for always having the language in the url, it was easier to implement all round and looked better to the user.

```
RewriteRule ^$ /en/ [L]   #default language
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [QSA,NE]   # first "slug" is presumed always language the rest is a page identifier
```

Here instead of directing to /en/ you could direct the user with no language set, to a geoip script or a script that chops up the user agent string for a language code or something to make a guess more accurate.